# How to show error message after not selecting any value from dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am facing one problem. I want to show alert message after not selecting any value from dropdown box:-
[image]

Here you see the image here opening hours will be shown When user not select any value from drop-down its OK user will be go proceed. If user select value from Monday First drop-down but not select any value from second drop-down and click on save and continue i want show alert message **please select opening hours in correct way**. and this is same for Tuesday and other days. Can anyone help me.

here is my html code:-

```
enter code here
<?php 
$from =array("6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23"); 
 $days = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday");  
 $to =array("7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22"); ?> 
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 fitness-time">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="additional">
            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="fitness-hours">
                    <h4>Opening Hours</h4>
                </span>
                <div>
                    <div class="info_user_detail">
                        <table class="table_info1 table-striped">
                            @foreach($days as $key=> $alldays)
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="checkbox no-margin">
                                        <label>
                                        <input name="days[]" value="{{ $alldays }}"type="checkbox">{{ $alldays }}
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="time-class">
                                        <select name="from[]"class="select-class from">
                                            <option value="">Select</option>
                                            @foreach($from as $froms)
                                            <option>{{ $froms }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="time-class">
                                        <select name="to[]"class="select-class to">
                                            <option value="">Select</option>
                                            @foreach($to as $to)
                                            <option>{{ $froms }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-save">
    <button id="CheckImageCount" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save And Coutinue </button>
</div>
```

Jquery Code:-

```
//enter code here
$('#CheckImageCount').on('click',function(){
        var value;
        $(".from").on('change',function(){
            value= $(this).val();
    });
    if(value != ""){
        var hoursvalue = $('.from').parents('td:first').next().find('.to').val();
        if(hoursvalue == ""){
            alert("PLease select opening hours in right way!"); return false;
        }else{
            alert("success"); return false;
        }
    }else{
        return true;
    }
});
```

Can anyone write JavaScript or jquery code to achieve this functionality. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: update <select name="from[]"class="select-class from"> to <select name="from[]"class="select-class from required">

Comment: this is a help forum, not a free programming agency. what have you tried yet? where are you stuck?

Comment: @jonas i have tried but jquery not working properly

Comment: Are you using some kind of plugins for validation or you just stick with Vanilla?

Comment: please edit your question and add that, its difficult to read it

Comment: @Faouzi i am using Laravel Framework 5.2 i want simple validation in javascript or jquery that alerts when user not selecting any one value from second dropdown

Comment: @Jonas i update it

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){//page is ready
alert("loading");
 var elems=[];

$('#form').on('submit',function(){// if form is submitted (please add the id form to your form)
    var value=elems.length;// if theres an unfinished answer elem, ret false
   if(value!=0){
   alert(value+" unfinished days ...");
   return false;
   }
    return true;
    });
   $(".from").on('change',function(){
    var val=0;
    var elem=$(this).parent().parent().parent(); //the day
    elem.find("input", function(){
     if($(this).val()){
     val++;//found a value
      }
     });
    alert("elem has:"+val) ;
    if(val==1){//this day is unfinished, add to array
            if(elems.indexOf(elem)<0){//not added yet
           elems.push(elem);//add to unfinished answer elems
            }
    }else{
           //answer complete remove from waiting
           var index=elems.indexOf(elem);
           if(index>=0){
          elems.splice(index,1);//remove from answer elems
          }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: did youve embedded jquery ( enter jquery ino the console to check)

Comment: yes i have alreday do console.log but when i select value from first dropdown and not select from second dropdown it submits the form

Comment: Now nothing is alerted it is redirecting me next page i also put form id

Comment: you understand my problem or not

Comment: there must at least be "loading", again have you embedded jquery?

Comment: yeah, my code checks if a day ( for example monday) has two values, if more than zero days have got two values, the form can be submitted

Comment: Its giving me error :- TypeError: elems.getIndexOf is not a function
elems.splice(elems.getIndexOf(elem),1);//remove from answer elems

Comment: oh, its indexOf instead of getIndexOf, sorry

Comment: when i don't choose value from second dropdown it alerts me 0 but after my form submits thats issue is occur

Comment: oh, i tought it would be enough to return a falsy (0) to cancel the submition, looks like it is required to return a real false ( value>0 ), see edit, sorry for this buggy answer

Comment: It alert twice time zero can you please alert the correct message

Comment: not working still when i select values from both dropdown it can't redirect to another page :(

Comment: edited again, my code required at least one finished day, now it requires no unfinished days...

Answer (score 1):

I am using jQuery traverse method to solve your problem, please check this.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#CheckImageCount').on('click',function(){
        
        // traverse tr element
        var error='false';
        $('.table_info1 tbody tr').each(function(){
          
            var from = $(this).find('td .from').val(); //find from class
            var to = $(this).find('td .to').val(); //find to class
            
            // Check if "to" is empty and "from" is selected
            if(from!="" && to==""){
               error='true';
               return 0;
            }
          
            // Check if "from" is empty and "to" is selected
            if(to!="" && from==""){
               error='true';
               return 0;
            }
        });
     
        if(error=='true'){
            console.log("PLease select opening hours in right way!");
        }else{
          console.log('Suceess');
        }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="additional">
 <div class="form-group">
  <span class="fitness-hours">
               <h4>Opening Hours</h4>
            </span>
  <div>
   <div class="info_user_detail">
    <table class="table_info1 table-striped">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <div class="checkbox no-margin">
         <label>
                                 <input name="days[]" value="Monday" type="checkbox">Monday                                        </label>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td>
        <div class="time-class">
         <select name="from[]" class="select-class from">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option>6</option>
                                    <option>7</option>
                                    <option>8</option>
                                    <option>9</option>
                                    <option>10</option>
                                 </select>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td>
        <div class="time-class">
         <select name="to[]" class="select-class to">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option>7</option>
                                    <option>8</option>
                                    <option>9</option>
                                    <option>10</option>
                                    <option>11</option>
                                    <option>12</option>
                                    <option>13</option>
                                 </select>
        </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <div class="checkbox no-margin">
         <label>
                                 <input name="days[]" value="Tuesday" type="checkbox">Tuesday                                        </label>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td>
        <div class="time-class">
         <select name="from[]" class="select-class from">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option>6</option>
                                    <option>7</option>
                                    <option>8</option>
                                    <option>9</option>
                                    <option>10</option>
                                    <option>11</option>
                                    
                                 </select>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td>
        <div class="time-class">
         <select name="to[]" class="select-class to">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option>7</option>
                                    <option>8</option>
                                    <option>9</option>
                                    <option>10</option>
                                    <option>11</option>
                                    <option>12</option>
                                    <option>13</option>
                                    
                                 </select>
        </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <div class="checkbox no-margin">
         <label>
                                 <input name="days[]" value="Wednesday" type="checkbox">Wednesday                                        </label>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td>
        <div class="time-class">
         <select name="from[]" class="select-class from">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option>6</option>
                                    <option>7</option>
                                    <option>8</option>
                                    <option>9</option>
                                    <option>10</option>
                                    <option>11</option>
                                    
                                 </select>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td>
        <div class="time-class">
         <select name="to[]" class="select-class to">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option>7</option>
                                    <option>8</option>
                                    <option>9</option>
                                    <option>10</option>
                                    <option>11</option>
                                    <option>12</option>
                                    <option>13</option>
                                    
                                 </select>
        </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <div class="checkbox no-margin">
         <label>
                                 <input name="days[]" value="Thursday" type="checkbox">Thursday                                        </label>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td>
        <div class="time-class">
         <select name="from[]" class="select-class from">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option>6</option>
                                    <option>7</option>
                                    <option>8</option>
                                    <option>9</option>
                                    <option>10</option>
                                    <option>11</option>
                                    <option>12</option>
                                    <option>13</option>
                                                                   </select>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td>
        <div class="time-class">
         <select name="to[]" class="select-class to">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option>7</option>
                                    <option>8</option>
                                    <option>9</option>
                                    <option>10</option>
                                    <option>11</option>
                                    <option>12</option>
                                    <option>13</option>
                                    <option>14</option>
                                    <option>15</option>
                                    <option>16</option>
                                   
                                 </select>
        </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <div class="checkbox no-margin">
         <label>
                                 <input name="days[]" value="Friday" type="checkbox">Friday                                        </label>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td>
        <div class="time-class">
         <select name="from[]" class="select-class from">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option>6</option>
                                    <option>7</option>
                                    <option>8</option>
                                    <option>9</option>
                                    <option>10</option>
                                    <option>11</option>
                                    <option>12</option>
                                    <option>13</option>
                                    <option>14</option>
                                    
                                 </select>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td>
        <div class="time-class">
         <select name="to[]" class="select-class to">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option>7</option>
                                    <option>8</option>
                                    <option>9</option>
                                    <option>10</option>
                                    <option>11</option>
                                    <option>12</option>
                                    <option>13</option>
                                    <option>14</option>
                                    <option>15</option>
                                    
                                 </select>
        </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <div class="checkbox no-margin">
         <label>
                                 <input name="days[]" value="Saturday" type="checkbox">Saturday                                        </label>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td>
        <div class="time-class">
         <select name="from[]" class="select-class from">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option>6</option>
                                    <option>7</option>
                                    <option>8</option>
                                    <option>9</option>
                                    <option>10</option>
                                    <option>11</option>
                                    <option>12</option>
                                    <option>13</option>
                                    <option>14</option>
                                    <option>15</option>
                                    
                                 </select>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td>
        <div class="time-class">
         <select name="to[]" class="select-class to">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option>7</option>
                                    <option>8</option>
                                    <option>9</option>
                                    <option>10</option>
                                    <option>11</option>
                                    <option>12</option>
                                    <option>13</option>
                                    
                                 </select>
        </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <div class="checkbox no-margin">
         <label>
                                 <input name="days[]" value="Sunday" type="checkbox">Sunday                                        </label>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td>
        <div class="time-class">
         <select name="from[]" class="select-class from">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option>6</option>
                                    <option>7</option>
                                    <option>8</option>
                                    <option>9</option>
                                    <option>10</option>
                                    <option>11</option>
                                    
                                 </select>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td>
        <div class="time-class">
         <select name="to[]" class="select-class to">
                                    <option value="">Select</option>
                                    <option>7</option>
                                    <option>8</option>
                                    <option>9</option>
                                    <option>10</option>
                                    <option>11</option>
                                    
                                 </select>
        </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-save">
 <button id="CheckImageCount" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save And Coutinue </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

add "required" in select tag "select name="from[]"class="select-class from" required". It will help you.

Comment: nope, he doesnt want all inputs to be required, just a pair should be complete...